# Approximation property for the quotient spaces of $C(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

As is known, for any compact space $T$ the Banach space $C(T)$ of all continuous functions on $T$ has the approximation property (see e.g. [Albrecht Pietsch, Operator ideals](https://books.google.ru/books/about/Operator_Ideals.html?id=SAyoAAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)). Is the same true for the (Hausdorff) quotient spaces of $C(T)$?

> Does every quotient space $C(T)/X$ of $C(T)$ (where $X$ is an arbitrary closed subspace in $C(T)$, not necessarily an ideal) has the approximation property?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212566/is-there-a-quotient-of-c-0-without-the-approximation-property)

Comment: Hm... I did not understand what paper @BillJohnson speaks about. Does this mean that the answer to my question is "no"?

Comment: The other way round. Bill Jhonson certain that counterexample exists and may be found in A. Szankowski's paper.